# Can't update Java Servlet when using Dynamic DNS url

Tags: java, servlets, dynamic

I have a java class that needs to update some data in the Java Servlet.
It works fine when i'm using the IP in my home network or even if i'm using my 
ISP ip (did the forwarding from the router).

But now, when i want to update the servlet with a Dynamic DNS that is actually
the same as my ISP adress it's not working.

The weird thing is that I can get data from the servlet using the Dynamic DNS.

That's my code: (I just stared the ip and DDNS adress)
NOTE: the Dynamic DNS (in the code: http://example.zapto.org) is the same as the stared ip (in the code: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084). When using the IP it works the DDNS not.

```
public class SendGsonToServlet {
public static boolean sendGson (String qrCode){

    try {
        String jsonStr = new Gson().toJson(qrCode);

//          URL servletURL = new URL("http://example.zapto.org/Android_Server/data");
            URL servletURL = new URL("http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8084/Android_Server/data");
//          URL servletURL = new URL("http://192.168.1.108:8084/Android_Server/data");

        // assumes protocol is http, could be https
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)servletURL.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.println(jsonStr);
//          out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());

    }catch (Exception e) {

    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Thanks you all and happy holidays :)

Comment: If you execute `ping example.zapto.org` from the same pc that you use for test what ip you got? And this pc is in or out your lan?

Comment: The ping gives me another IP. The Server is at the same network, but I want to connect from anywhere with DDNS.

Answer (score 0):

If the ping give you another IP address, and if with this IP address your test fails, maybe:

- Or you cannot reach your service within your LAN using your public IP;
- Or DDNS fails in IP evaluation;
- Or your ISP doesn't give you a public IP and it use NAT to its private subnet.

Comment: So do you have maybe an idea how can I use the Dynamic DNS to send my servlet data? and how came that I can get data from it? Thanks a lot man!